# Div and Mod in big.Float

Tags: go, division, modulo

big.Int supports both Division and Modulo operations. Why division and modulo operations are not supported in big.Float? Is Quo() is different from division? Is there math.Mod(x, y float64) equivalent for big.Float

Answer (score 0):

Division or quotient operation on integers and big integers produce integer value while on floats it produce float. That's why operations have different precision and mathematical sense.

```
var x, y int = 5, 3
z:=x/y    //give you 1
```

but

```
var x, y float32 = 5, 3
z:=x/y   //give you 1.6666666
```

Modulo or reminder operations didn't defined on floats because it's hard to elaborate what them can mean. Same with math/big

Comment: I meant the math.Mod equivalent for big.Float